# How to find different dates under one series and choose the first date only of each series in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
df<- structure(list(TIME = c("25/01/2011", "25/01/2011", "25/01/2011", 
"25/01/2011", "16/11/2011", "26/01/2011", "16/11/2011", "16/11/2011", 
"25/01/2011", "25/01/2011", "16/11/2011", "16/11/2011", "27/09/2011", 
"16/11/2011", "16/11/2011", "07/07/2012", "16/11/2011", "21/09/2012", 
"16/11/2011", "26/01/2011"), Series = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 1L), block = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), RE = c(1.28, 1.52, 2.9, 1.15, 1.72, 0.22, 2.45, 
2.32, 1.2, 1.13, 1.9, 0.78, 5.06, 2.03, 1.7, 5.62, 1.93, 4.21, 
2.16, 0.59)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

In my following procedure, I need to calculate the average of the data by `TIME` and `block`. However, as you can see from `df`, each series sometimes corresponds to 2 or 3 different dates. I want to find all these differences and change the date to the first date under the same series. I have no idea how to realize this, by loop function maybe?

df<- tapply(mol.df$RE,list(mol.df$TIME,mol.df$block),mean) #here you will get a list

Hope someone could help.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouped by 'Series', convert the 'TIME' to `Date` class, get the `min` value and add as group before getting the `mean` of 'RE'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    group_by(Series) %>%
     mutate(TIME = min(dmy(TIME))) %>% 
    group_by(TIME, .add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(RE = mean(RE), .groups = 'drop')
```